# "Call a number" or "call to a number"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if I have to use *to* after *call* in the following context?

> With this cell phone plan you'll get 500 minutes of calling numbers other cell phone carriers.
>
> With this cell phone plan you'll get 500 minutes of calling **to** numbers other cell phone carriers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, we **call a number**, not "call *to* a number".

For example,

> [I call the number on the card that the salesman gave to me.](https://books.google.com/books?id=gJEowY_FHvwC&pg=PA64&dq=%22call%20the%20number%20on%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi35tGxgZzvAhWbFVkFHcInCocQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg)

> [Telemarketers that call a number on the no-call list can be fined](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gy-YuX-RzBEC&pg=PA84&dq=%22call%20a%20number%20on%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP_PHEgZzvAhWjMlkFHa0aD2sQ6AEwA3oECAAQAg)

---

There are some other issues with your sentence, though.  You need a preposition after "numbers".  I would say the numbers are **on** other cell phone carriers, or **of** other cell phone carriers.

Also, using *calling* is unidiomatic: it would be more fluent to say you you get 500 minutes of **calls**.  *Calling* sounds more like the specific action of dialing the number and waiting for it to ring, while the *call* is the entire conversation.  For example, the US telephone company Verizon says

> [You can add up to 500 minutes per month of direct-dialed calls to 120 countries and destinations (98 countries for calls to mobile phones).](https://www.verizon.com/info/international-calling/)